# Insert Blank Page on Page Break BIRT

Tags: javascript, birt

Is it possible to insert a blank page whenever there is a page break in BIRT? For example, if the number of rows in a table exceeds one page, rather than immediately continuing the table on the next page, I want to first insert a blank page, then continue outputting the table.

I would think it would be possible through javascript on the onPageBreak event of the table, but so far, I have been unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand a little more on the problem you are trying to solve?  It almost sounds like you are trying to overcome a printing issue.

Comment: The bank requires that our check pdfs be arranged in this fashion.

Comment: I am not able to help you, but you are more likely to get a helpful response if you post what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: I have never seen a hook to do that in BIRT designer. One possibility is to use a 3rd party PDF tool to insert a blank page after PDF generation (assuming you are printing to PDF and not web viewer).